# RegExp: Identifying poor regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm working with Regular Expressions and was just curious about how authors of RegExp go about identifying improvements with the patterns they write. For example, here's a pattern for identifying a simple currency expression (omitting the literal symbol or AS2/AS3 identifier for simplicity). To me, this appears pretty concise and when running in a JS environment it identified my test cases accurately. Yet, I can see that I've used 3 IF/ELSE statements and perhaps it is this use case that makes my expression longer than it should or needed to be. Is there a general rule of thumb when it comes to RegExp optimisation? Or is the simply the nature of the language that makes the case that "if it works it is the correct expression"?

Thanks for reading and your feedback, suggestions or critiques.

RegExp Pattern:

```
/((\s\.){1})|((\d+){1})((\.\d+|\,\d+)|(\d+)){1,}/
```

RegExp Breakdown:

```
/* A */ ((\s\.){1}) /** whitespace followed by period once **/

/* B */ ((\d+){1}) /** any number of digits occurs once before broken pattern **/       

((\s\.){1})|((\d+){1}) /** either pattern A or B **/

/* C */ (\.\d+|\,\d+) /** either period or comma preceeding a pattern of digits **/

/* D */ (\d+) /** any number of digits occurs before broken pattern **/

((\.|\,)|(\d+)){1,} /** either pattern A or B repeated at least once **/

/* Final */

((\s\.){1})|((\d+){1})((\.\d+|\,\d+)|(\d+)){1,}
```

Comment: "if it works it is the correct expression" --- if it works it is definitely *correct*.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @zerkms !

Comment: There's no general procedure for something like this. It's like any other aspect of programming and optimization -- when you run into a performance problem, you examine your code and try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Regular expressions can be particularly tricky, because it's not always obvious what will be expensive.

Comment: @Barmar certainly agree with you on these points based on the feedback from the previous contributor. Have you identified in your programing any general rules of thumb that might suggest that a RegExp could be expensive? Again, I imagine that the answer is probably a "not really" but just in case! My idea is that if it is a particularly long single line expression, it is likely a large overhead evaluation.

Comment: If you want to identify signs of a poor regex, you can put in your top list, regexes that use the quantifier `{1}`. In general, try to limit the number of branches `asdasd|dfgdfgfg|dfgfdgd|dfgfg|....`, use the small character classes (`[0-9]` is better than `\d` when `\d` contains all unicode digits).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for your comment! Regarding the quantifier `{}` is this referring to a redundant use case? For example: `/\d/` versus `/\d{1}/`? According to regexr both select single digits, but I imagine that the second use case over-complicates it.

Comment: Not over-complicate, it's useless. In general try to track all useless things, (useless quantifiers, useless capturing groups `((((aaaaa))))`, a capture group is only useful when you want to capture something, otherwise use a non capturing group).

Comment: Thanks for your expanded answer @CasimiretHippolyte. That's a really good example.

Comment: You can perhaps write the same pattern like this: `\s\.|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*` and if you want to limit the impact of this last alternation, you can use this trick: `(?=[\s\d])(?:\s\.|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)` to quickly discard all positions in the string that don't start with a whitespace or a digit without to have to try the two branches of the alternation.

Comment: This trick is called "first character discrimination".

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte great example again. If you like, feel free to respond to this post as the answer and I can accept it. You've done an excellent job and I think you've raised a case that if your RegExp is simple, short and use the most accurate character identifiers and avoid character wildcards, groups and conditionals where it can, it is likely the most optimised and correct form of all available ways of writing the expression.

Comment: best way of identifying improvements is to see what the experts do and incorporate their standards in your regexes.